# How can I call an UWP API from a C++ desktop application

Tags: c++, win-universal-app, desktop

I would like to access Bluetooth LE devices using the corresponding UWP APIs. However, my application is a "classic" C++ application (3D game) that can't run as a UWP app. Is there a way to do that? Accorind to [enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn554295(v=vs.85).aspx) these APIs are published, but I don't know the steps to access them I have only found some posts for Windows 8/8.1 apps that include the Windows.winmd and Platform.winmd metadata files and set the /ZW compilation flag, but this doesn't seem to apply to Windows 10.

Comment: I don't know how true is this, but I read somewhere that Microsoft is no longer backporting UWP APIs to win32… which is really bad as it looks to me like if they are forcing devs to use UWP to use new technologies.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this, as the Bluetooth classes (e.g., [`BluetoothLEAdvertisement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisement.aspx)) are marked up with [`DualApiPartitionAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.metadata.dualapipartitionattribute.aspx) (callable from desktop and UWP apps).

Using one of the older Win8.1 desktop samples should give you a good starting point for calling the APIs without requiring /ZW or referencing the winmd files. A good example is the [desktop toast API sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Sending-toast-notifications-71e230a2).

If you go that route, you can use classic COM to create the UWP/WinRT classes [via WRL helpers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973459.aspx).

Answer (score -3):

You can use the web that you make a web server and the C++ application use the same server and if UWP send the info to server then it will send the info to C++ application.
To safe,the UWP can't use the desktop app.